# Is it possible to speed up a program using a VM?

Tags: windows-10, archlinux, winelib

I’m trying to collect footage from a game. Is it at all possible to have it play at say, twice the speed?

In the sense that if I run it for an hour, I want to capture multiple hours of in-game time.

Answer (score 1):

i dont really know, what you mean but you can record only every second frame, so the video looks twice as fast

Comment: That would still just give an hour of footage per hour.